# Questions in tag filter appear multiple times

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, tag-filters

I just noticed that questions appear multiple times in my tag filter on stackexchange.com:
[image]

Nothing against four times Jon Skeet in a row, but this seems to be a bug in the tag filter, as these questions only appear one time on the SE sites themselves. It seems to only affect newer questions, the older questions are unaffected in the same tag filter.

Comment: SE's secret Jon Skeet cloning project seems to be going well.

Comment: This is also affecting the email alerts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94835/duplicate-items-in-email-alerts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a slight mishap over the weekend.  A service that's responsible for aggregating activity across the Stack Exchange network (providing the lion's share of the data SE.com displays) got spun up twice.

This lead to a dueling banjos sort of affair where lots of content got "double aggregated" (technical N-aggregated, as you can see in your screenshot).  The affects have been cleaned up, and I'm working on making the service a tad more robust in the face of this sort of failure.